# Mongoose paginate - one document always is lost

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I have db with 6 documents and here is my route:

```
router.get('', async (req, res) => {
const search = req.query.search !=null ? req.query.search : "";
const page = req.query.page !=null ? req.query.page : 1;
const limit = req.query.limit !=null ? req.query.limit : 4;
try {
    User.paginate({fullname: {$regex: search, $options: '-i'}}, {page: page, limit: limit, customLabels: myCustomLabels, select:'-email -password'}, async (err, result) => {
            res.json(result)
    }
    );
}
catch(e){
    res.status(500).json({ message: 'somthing went wrong, try again...  ERROR :' + e });
}
```

})

In first response (1 page, 4 items) i can see that total document count is 6, but when i sent second request (for 2nd page) it says that total count of douments is 5, and sent only one document in array.
If i change items per page to 5 - secon request will sent empty array too. 
I don't understand why one documents always is lost

UPD: its work correct when i delete {fullname: {$regex: search, $options: '-i'}}

I don't have any idea why it lost with regex option. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's better to mention if you're using a library or just add the require/import part to your sample code, cause `Model.paginate()` does not exist on mongoose.

You are also mixing async/await with traditional callback syntax. You could make your code much cleaner and simpler.

I think one of your documents might not have the fullname field. that's why it does not come up when you do a search. Anyways, give the code a try:

```
router.get('', async (req, res) => {
  const { search = "", page = 1, limit = 4 } = req.query;
  const paginate = {};
  if (search) {
    paginate.fullname = {
      $regex: search, 
      $options: '-i'
    }
  };
  try {
    const result = await User.paginate(paginate, {
      page, 
      limit, 
      customLabels: myCustomLabels, 
      select:'-email -password'
    });
    return res.json(result);
  } catch(e) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: 'somthing went wrong, try again...  ERROR :' + e });
  }
```